# Security context in a trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I'll start of by saying that I'm a .net guy having to play in a salesforce.com world right now.

My question is this;

Within the context of an pre-update/insert trigger can I set the value of a field that the user (the user that is updating the object when the trigger fires) does NOT have on their page layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

However, the user might still be restricted from modifying that field due to restrictions on the field itself.  If it's a standard object, you can go to Setup > App Setup > Customize.  Then choose the object in question and go to the "Fields" link.  There you can see each field on the object and view the field-level security.